# How do I set up Ruby + Thin server in Windows?

Tags: windows, ruby

I need to setup the "Thin" server on Windows, but I'm running into some issues, anyone able to help?

Comment: I brought this back from -1 as the question really was answered and, therefore, was clear enough to be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have Ruby + Ruby Gems + the DevKit from the RubyInstaller site installed already, this should do the trick:

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
gem install thin
```

RubyInstaller + DevKit can be found at http://rubyinstaller.org

Edit: Also, make sure to run `gem update --system` then `gem update` to make sure everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, found that site when searching for the best way to install Ruby on Windows, dent know about the rubygems updating part though, going to give this a try.

Comment: Hey hey! It worked! That's a ton man, now I can finally work on my Ruby sites on my Windows PC.

Comment: +1 because I, also, had a problem with "thin" and your answer helped.